# AS3 flash CC I want to set the width of the parent Movieclip of a Textfield

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip, flash-cs6, displayobject

I have dynamically created a bunch of textfields, the number of which depends on xml input. The textfields need to be button-enabled, so I thought the easiest solution is to put them in a movieclip and buttonMode that movieclip.

The hierarchy looks like this: main (extends MovieClip) -> klankoefening (a MovieClip) -> Textfieldparent (a MovieClip) -> Textfield

I have a variable **maxw** which contains the biggest textfield's width and I want all my Textfieldparents to have this width.

I'm trying to do it like this:

```
//generate textfields
keuzes = new XMLList(lijstOpties.categorie.(@cat == catname));
var nrs:int = keuzes.keuze.length(); //aantal keuzemogelijkheden
var maxw:int = 0; //grootste breedte tf, nodig voor bepalen breedte knoppen

for (var nr:int = 0; nr < nrs; nr++) { 
    var tf:TextField = createTextfield(werkfmt);
    tf.text = keuzes.keuze[nr].toString();
    tf.autoSize = "center";
    tf.background = true;
    tf.backgroundColor = 0xffcc33;
    tf.border = true;
    tf.borderColor = 0x000000;
    tf.name = "keuzetf";
    tf.selectable = false;
    tf.x = 0;
    tf.y = 0;

    if (tf.width > maxw) {maxw = tf.width;}

    var tfcontainer:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    tfcontainer.buttonMode = true;
    tfcontainer.name = keuzes.keuze[nr].toString();
    tfcontainer.addChild(tf);

    klankoefening.addChildAt(tfcontainer,nr);
}

for (var an:int = 0; an < 3; an++) {
    var mcs:MovieClip = klankoefening.getChildAt(an) as MovieClip;
    mcs.width = maxw;
    trace ("mcs " + mcs.width);

    var mtf:TextField = mcs.getChildAt(0) as TextField;
            trace ("mtf " + mtf.text);
}
```

the trace results are

```
mcs 32.05
mcs 33
mcs 21.25
```

Which I find odd, because I stated in my second loop that the width for all Textfieldparents should be set to **maxw**. What is happening?

Comment: If you're setting the width of the button after adding the button to the movieClip, you're going to get stretching of the TextField within its button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider drawing an underlaying `Rectangle` of desired width and height. You can use `mcs.graphics` to do that. The trick is, width of a `DisplayObjectContainer` is a calculated property, and changing it will likely result in changing scale. Say, a MC has two shapes as chilren, one at (1000,0) and another at (0,0), and both have width of 10 - the resultant width of that MC will be 1010. So, instead of changing width, simulate its change by drawing a rectangle on the MC.

```
mcs.graphics.clear();
mcs.graphics.lineStyle(0,0,0);
mcs.graphics.beginFill(0x808080,0); // bogus filled rect, to capture events
mcs.graphics.drawRect(0,0,maxw,maxh); // height is needed too
mcs.graphics.endFill();
```

Answer (score 0):

After thinking a bit more about your problem, I think your issue is that the buttons you're adding the text to have a width entirely defined by the TextField, and because you're set the text to autoSize, it's snapping back to it's original width.

What you will need to do to make the width more indicative of what you need, and allow for easy clicking on the buttons is to create a transparent rectangle in the tfContainer mc, set the width of the tfContainer, and then add the text to the button.

Comment: I tried turning off the autoSize but that made no difference. Because Vespers answer is a bit more detailed I accepted that (and shamelessly copied the code) Thanks for your help!